# return loop in an if statement

Tags: java

Can you please help me with this code ?

---

Any advice is much appreciated - Newbie2Java
I have had some great input - thanks (missing the link)

This is my code:

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Question5WIP {

```
/**
 * @param args


public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // boolean correctInput = false; // assume we dont have correct input
    //  while (!correctInput){       // continue as long as not correct input

    int hourValue = 0;
    Scanner in;
    while (!(hourValue > 0 && hourValue <= 12)) {
        System. out.println("Please enter the hours (between 1 and 12): ");                                  
        in = new Scanner(System.in); // User input hour value.

        hourValue = in.nextInt();

        if (!(hourValue > 0 && hourValue <= 12)) {
            System.out.println("Hour Value should be between 1 and 12, please try again "); // invalid hours.

        }
    }

    int minuteValue = 0;
    // Scanner in;
    while (!(minuteValue > 0 && hourValue <= 60)) {
        System. out.println("Please enter the minutes (between 1 and 60): ");                                  
        in = new Scanner(System.in); // User input hour value.

        minuteValue = in.nextInt();

        if (!(minuteValue > 0 && minuteValue <= 60)) {
            System.out.println("Invalid entry, please try again: "); // invalid hours.
            return;
        }
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this its giving correct answer

```
   import java.util.Scanner;

   public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int hourValue = 0;
    Scanner in;
    while (!(hourValue > 0 && hourValue <= 12)) {
        System. out.println("Please enter the hours (between 1 and 12): ");                                  
        in = new Scanner(System.in); // User input hour value.

        hourValue = in.nextInt();

        if (!(hourValue > 0 && hourValue <= 12)) {
            System.out.println("Hour Value should be between 1 and 12,
                        please try again "); // invalid hours.

        }
    }

    int minuteValue;
    System.out.println("Please enter the minutes (between 1 and 60): ");
        // The program prompts for the hour.
    in = new Scanner(System.in); // User input hour value.

    minuteValue = in.nextInt();

    if (!(minuteValue >= 0 && minuteValue <= 60)) {
        System.out.println("Minute Value should be between 0 and 60,
                     please  try again "); // invalid minutes.
        return;

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you for your post, most helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int hourValue, minuteValue;
        Scanner in;

        while (true) {
            System. out.println("Please enter the hours (between 1 and 12): ");
            in = new Scanner(System.in); // User input hour value.
            hourValue = in.nextInt();
            if (hourValue < 0 || hourValue > 12)) 
                System.out.println("Hour Value should be between 1 and 12, please try again ");
            else
                break;
        }

        while(true) {
            System.out.println("Please enter the minutes (between 1 and 60): ");
            in = new Scanner(System.in);
            minuteValue = in.nextInt();
            if (minuteValue < 0 || minuteValue > 60)) 
                System.out.println("Minute Value should be between 0 and 60,please  try again ");//invalid minutes.
            else
                break;
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it with a while loop! Like this:

```
int hourValue; 
while(!(hourValue > 0 && hourValue <= 12)) {
    System.out.println("Please enter the hours (between 1 and 12): "); //The program prompts for the hour. 
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); // User input hour value.

    hourValue = in.nextInt();        

    if(!(hourValue > 0 && hourValue <= 12)){
           System.out.println("Hour Value should be between 1 and 12, please try again "); //invalid hours.
           return; 

    }
}

    int minuteValue; 
    System.out.println("Please enter the minutes (between 1 and 60): "); //The program prompts for the hour. 
    in = new Scanner(System.in); // User input hour value.

    minuteValue = in.nextInt();        

    if(!(minuteValue >= 0 && minuteValue <= 60)){
           System.out.println("Minute Value should be between 0 and 60, please try again "); //invalid minutes. 
           return;
```

Now you only have to do the same for the minutes.

Comment: In the second `if` you don't need return statement, because you must loop to enter hour value again. Instead you must add  additional else block with break from the loop if hour is acceptable

Comment: Thank you for your post, most helpful.

Comment: @Rouxster if it helped you, give them an upvote and/or accept answer

Answer (score 0):

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
int hourValue = 0;
Scanner in;
while (!(hourValue > 0 && hourValue <= 12)) {
    System. out.println("Please enter the hours (between 1 and 12): ");                                  
    in = new Scanner(System.in); // User input hour value.

    hourValue = in.nextInt();

    if (!(hourValue > 0 && hourValue <= 12)) {
        System.out.println("Hour Value should be between 1 and 12,
                    please try again "); // invalid hours.

    }
}

int minuteValue;
System.out.println("Please enter the minutes (between 1 and 60): ");
    // The program prompts for the hour.
in = new Scanner(System.in); // User input hour value.

minuteValue = in.nextInt();

if (!(minuteValue >= 0 && minuteValue <= 60)) {
    System.out.println("Minute Value should be between 0 and 60,
                 please  try again "); // invalid minutes.
    return;
```